# What populated "History" tab in encryption statistics?

Tags: platform-encryption, shield-encryption, shield

When I navigate to Platform Encryption Statistics --> then toggle over to the History tab, I see a table with 4 columns. They are:

1. Encrypted Field History
2. Unencrypted Field History
3. Encrypted Feed
4. Tracking Unencrypted Feed Tracking

What Populates these values?  If, for example, `Account: Name` is encrypted, and someone changes the name, would it populate the "Encrypted Field History" value for that field?  I am curious where these values are generated overall, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are showing encryption statistics for field history and feed tracking data. You will only see that tab if you've enabled encryption for these in Advanced Settings.

As for what populates the field history and/or feed tracking data - I would point you to the help documents about those features:
[Field History](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=5)
and
[Feed Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_feed_tracking_overview.htm&type=5)